# cakephp and dompdf require_once throws include error

Tags: php, cakephp, dompdf

i have dompdf in my vendor folder and  including it in my view like below

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'DomPdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php'
```

);

this throws a fatal error:

```
Error: require_once() [<a href='http://php.net/function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/r2d2/web-php/sms/app/Vendor/DomPdf/dompdf_config.inc.php' (include_path='/home/r2d2/web-php/sms/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
File: /home/r2d2/web-php/sms/app/View/ExamsScores/one_card_generate.ctp
Line: 149
```

why is this not working..all other files include just fine..so i know its not the require_once line

Comment: well, does that path work? e.g. does the file and the directories actually exist? are they readable by the user running this script?

Comment: @Marc B  yes the files and folders exist.i even tried with tcpdf which works and permissions are well set

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste dompdf_config.inc.php absolute path?

If is out from app project can't access it and you need put absolute path

Comment: it was an issue with permissions and i fixed it